# Give an example of a locally compact Hausdorff space which is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

> Give an example of a locally compact Hausdorff space which is not compact.

Would the following be valid? Could someone give an example using a different topology? $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{\text{euclidian}})$?

I have proved $(X,\tau_{\text{discrete}})$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

Lets take $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{\text{discrete}}$, then this is locally compact and Hausdorff, but not compact.

Let $[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and consider the open cover $\bigcup_{x\in [0,1]} \{x\}$. This cover does not contain a finite subcover, so $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Comment: How about $\mathbb {R}$ with its usual topology?

Comment: Yes, an infinite discrete space is locally compact and not compact.

Comment: @zhw. Could you provide an example of a open cover, but without an finite subcover? I guess $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} {]-n, n[}$ would do?

Comment: That will do fine.